# MongoDB aggregation queries in sails js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sails.js, sails-mongo

How do we write the aggregation queries in sails js other than sum and average.
Like we have `Model.aggregate()` method in mongoose so how is the same thing done using sails-mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the available datastore manager in order to make a native query. Aggregate is not a waterline supported feature.

Documentation: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/manager

Here's an example:

```
const db = ModelName.getDatastore().manager;
const rawCollection = db.collection(tableName);

if (!rawCollection)
    return res.serverError(
        "Could not find tableName collection"
    );

return rawCollection
    .aggregate(
        [
            {
                $match: {
                    createdAt: {
                        $gte: from,
                        $lte: to,
                    },
                },
            },
            { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
            {
                $group: {
                },
            },
            { $limit: page * limit + limit },
            { $skip: page * limit },
        ],
        {
            cursor: {
                batchSize: 100,
            },
        }
    )
    .toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);

        let results = {
            items: result,
            total: result.length,
        };

        return res.json(results);
    });
```

Change `ModelName` and `tableName` to be what you need.